# Issue with grunt creating output CSS at multiple places

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs

I am having a little issue with grunt creating output `CSS` files.

My `Gruntfile.js` is configured to take inputs from certain folders and create compiled `CSS` files in my output folders and it works fine. However, this process also creates `.css` and `.min.css` files at the same location where my `.scss` file exists.

This is what is happening right now -

- Input folder path: `/app/css/test.scss`
- Output folder path: `/public/css/test.css` and  `/public/css/test.min.css`.
  Output files were also created  at `/app/css/test.css` and `/app/css/test.min.css` which I don't want.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Below is the code snippet for Sass from `Gruntfile.js`

```
sass: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                lineNumbers: true,
                style: 'expanded'
            },
            files: {
                '../public/css/test.css': 'app/css/test.scss'
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed',
                quiet: true
            },
            files: {
                '../public/css/test.min.css': 'app/css/test.scss'
            }
        }
    },
```

I couldn't find anything about this online. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was.

I had installed a Visual Studio plugin called Sassy Studio so whenever I modified any scss file in Visual Studio, it used to compile it and output the css in the same directory as the .scss file.

To stop this from happening, I went to Visual Studio Options, from the left side select "Sassy Studio" and then on the right side turn "Generate .css on save" and "Generate minified .css on save" options "False".

Answer (score 0):

That's what the `cwd` option is for.

```
files: [
    {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'app/css/',
        src: 'test.scss',
        dest: '../public/css/'
    }

]
```

http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically